# Select N saturated colors with largest visual separation

Tags: python, colors

I'm generating colors to draw boxes around detected objects in videos. My videos have low saturation, so I want highly saturated box colors for maximum visibility. I'm using the following function to randomly generate these colors:

```
def gen_color():
    '''Generate a highly saturated color'''
    h,s,l = random.random(), 0.5 + random.random()/2.0, 0.4 + random.random()/5.0
    r,g,b = [int(256*i) for i in colorsys.hls_to_rgb(h,l,s)]
    return [r,g,b]
```

However, if I need to generate `N` boxes, for example N=20, if I simply make repeated calls to this function, the N generated colors often have many that are near visually identical, and so it becomes hard to distinguish between some of them.

So my question is, how can I generate N colors with high saturation, that are maximally distinct from one another (I guess this would be in terms of both hue and lightness)? I don't work with color spaces often, so I'm not sure how to approach the problem.

Comment: I know you tagged python but this Matlab function might be useful  https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29702-generate-maximally-perceptually-distinct-colors. [Source code](https://viewer.mathworks.com/?viewer=plain_code&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathworks.com%2Fmatlabcentral%2Fmlc-downloads%2Fdownloads%2Fsubmissions%2F29702%2Fversions%2F3%2Fcontents%2Fdistinguishable_colors.m&embed=web)

Comment: Thanks, will take a look!

Comment: Try [clicking on the functions tab and then clicking on the function itself](https://imgur.com/R4bHIE4.png)

Comment: Please note the components of your request:  (1) How do I measure a "distance" between two colors; (2) How do I design a color space?  (3) What algorithm will generate a maximally discriminated distribution of points around an as-yet-unspecified space?

These are research items for you.  You're essentially asking SO people to consult for you and reduce your research curve.  This is against site standards.

Comment: Cool man. The first commenter linked me to a function that solved my problem directly.